# get session in template file

Tags: template, session

I am setting a session variable on an event triggered when the url have an extra variable name "pcode" with the following code.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setPcode($pcode);
```

Now when getting the session from one of template file with the following code..

```
$data=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPcode();
Mage::Log($data);
```

**Edit:**Enable the log From back-end and checked

but I am getting nothing.

I also tried the same code by calling a model and also from calling an ajax function from the template but have the same results.

Edit:

When I am getting the session value after setting get, it retrieves the value but in another template page, its have no value.

```
$request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('front')->getRequest();
        $pcode  = $request->pcode;
        if(isset($pcode))
            //Mage::getModel(‘core/cookie’)->set('pcode', $pcode);
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setPcode($pcode);
            $data=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPcode();
                Mage::Log($data);
        exit;
```

**Edit:** Enable the log From back-end and check in var/log/system.log file your value will logged or not.

Answer (score 3):

you can set the session using set, getting value using get and unset session using uns.

```
Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->setMySessionVariable(‘MyValue’); 

$myValue  =  Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->getMySessionVariable();

echo $myValue;
```

To Unset the session

```
Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->unsMySessionVariable();
```

Comment: I am using the same method but unable to get the session. what's wrong with my code??

Comment: check you got value in $pcode or not

Comment: When I put the code echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPcode();
exactly after setting it, I am getting the value. however later in a template file, noting is retrieved.

Comment: means your session is expired some how

Comment: No its not expired, I have modified the question, plz review.

Comment: I update your question

Comment: Thanks, fixed it, the value was updated to no value in some cases.